Attempting to count affected rows, not total occurrences of a keyword
I am attempting to count the number of application's comments that include a key word, not the total count of the keyword.
i.e. creating the measure on the right from the table on the left.

I have put together this measure, but this counts the total amount of keyword occurrences.
Applications with Keywords Count Measure =
VAR _search_word =
    SELECTEDVALUE ('Keywords Table'[Keywords])
VAR _result =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Application Detail Table' ),
        CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Application Detail Table'[Comments], _search_word )
    )
RETURN
    _result

Please help!
Thank you!
I attempted to use the above formula, and cannot determine how many applications are affected, only total number of keywords occurrences.

Not quite sure what you mean, your measure works exactly as shown on your screenshot - https://i.sstatic.net/6eIwobBM.png

If i got your point correctly,To count the number of application's comments that include a key word, not the total count of the keyword,Please try below measure..
VAR _search_word =
    SELECTEDVALUE ('Keywords Table'[Keywords])
VAR _result =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Application Detail Table'[ApplicationID] ),
        CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Application Detail Table'[Comments], _search_word )
    )
RETURN
    _result


The measure you are using should work.
Applications with Keywords Count Measure =
VAR _search_word =
    SELECTEDVALUE ('Keywords Table'[Keywords])
VAR _result =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Application Detail Table' ),
        CONTAINSSTRING ( 'Application Detail Table'[Comments], _search_word )
    )
RETURN
    _result


